# What is f in front of few math functions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning some basic modules in python and came across math function.

I observed 'f' in front of few functions like fabs, fmod, frexp, fsum etc.

may I know what is this 'f' in these functions

Comment: means it returns `float` type.

Comment: Didn't waste any time seeing what those functions do, I take it.

Comment: then why not it is available for ceil funtion

Comment: What is the point of having a floating-point version of a function that returns an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the floating point returning version of some functions that may return an integer. Example:

```
>>> abs(50)
50
>>> from math import *
>>> fabs(50)
50.0
>>>
```

since return type is different, you cannot have only one function

Note: As dawg mentionned it could check input type and return the same, but that may not be what you want. Everyone would end up forcing the type to `float` or `int` to make sure.

Comment: Well you *could* have only one function (by type testing the argument) but it would be slower and more confusing...

Comment: not to mention it looks very much like C counterparts.